# FOSS to non-FOSS licence change CRAN package

Tags: r, package, cran

I recently decided to commercialize parts of my code in a package I had written for R, after submitting two versions under the LGPL licence to CRAN. On the third update, I changed the licensing from LGPL to CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 to accommodate for this.

However, after submission, I received a message from the guys at CRAN stating that it is not possible to change a free and open source (FOSS) licence to a non-FOSS. After suggesting two alternatives:

1. Remove all previous versions of the package which had an LGPL licence OR
2. Change licensing for previous versions to the non-FOSS licence

Both were rejected with the following message:

> we cannot remove archived versions
>   with a FOSS license, and we do not accept changes to a non-FOSS license for commercialization reasons.

Could someone shed some more light on why this is not possible on this and any alternatives I could take, if any?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: You're asking for legal advice. We are not lawyers.  "But some random guy on the interwebitudes said it was ok" will not save your butt if you get hauled into court.


Comment: Note to all: "open source" can be commercial. Can you use "proprietary" as the opposite of "open source"? Or "closed source" if that's the case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot retroactively change your license *for already published code*. Previous releases remain available forever -- that is part of the "contract" between the "publisher" of code (here, you) and its users.

You are of course free to re-license *new* versions.

And CRAN is equally free to refuse to distribute commercial code.  Because if you look more carefully, you will note that the 4600+ packages on CRAN are all Open Source and not commercial.

Comment: `gpclib` can be free, for non-commercial use, does that count? :)

Comment: There are a few packages like that but I reckon they would not get admitted to CRAN today.

Comment: When I searched around, I found that some packages were indeed free for non-commercial use, including the CC licence. Is this still permitted, provided your first submission was submitted under a non-FOSS licence? or do they now completely refuse to distribute commercial code?

Comment: Only the CRAN maintainers will be able to tell you for sure, but I think saying that the standards were tightened over the years is fair.  A few packages were grandfathered because other packages depended on them. Also note that some packages even got extra licenses to make them "free enough" for CRAN.

Answer (score 3):

Read the [CRAN Repository Policy](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html). You gave them the right to distribute the packages in perpetuity via your choice to license them as LGPL. You cannot retroactively change a legal agreement. Even if CRAN removed the LGPL versions of your package, *anyone* could re-publish that source code because you gave *every* user the right to distribute the source code.  This is the entire point of FOSS.

Your only alternative is: re-license your package as commercial and release/distribute it yourself.